How To Enable HTTPS Protocol To True When Connecting To AWS S3 In DataGrip
I am able to establish a connection using S3cmd to my AWS storage, but I am unable to make the connection on DataGrip.
I am using all the same Parameters (Access Key), (Secret Key), (S3 Endpoint), (BucketURL), I am not using any HTTP Proxy or Encryption, The only different parameter that I have on S3cmd that I don't have on DataGrip is (Use HTTPS protocol: True), I am using the JetBrains Big Data Tools plugin. Is it possible to set this parameter, or is there any other recommended GUI I can use to connect to my storage? Although I prefer to use DataGrip if possible.

Side-note: These days, it is probably better to use the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) rather than s3cmd (which is only updated about once per year).

NOTE
This answer is not to enable HTTPS but to connect to s3 using datagrip. as that is the main target here.
you can simply connect to s3 from datagrip in following steps:

setup you default profile in aws cli with aws access key , aws secret key , default region and output. make sure your access key has necessary s3 permission.

open datagrip, open big data tool and select s3




do the following settings as per your s3 bucket setup in AWS,  test the connection (this is mine)


If the connection succeeds just click ok and you are good to go.



as you demanded , to access s3 storage from datagrip

Thank you, this worked, I only had an issue because I needed to add http:// before my endpoint

sure, you are welcome i am ready for upvote :D

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I get this message when I try lol, I have been using stack for years but never posted any questions this is my first. So I cannot upvote yet :(

its okey i  was just fooling around, i am glad that my answer worked for you
